# After Updating to Marshmallow the App runs thrice while I run from my PC

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, launching-application

I received marshmallow update for my Moto X Play few days before and I updated it, After updating it and whenever I run my app from Android Studio it launches three times. But where as I click the icon, which is run previously it just opens once.

Comment: are you having three instances installed for your app.?

Comment: No only single instance is installed, but when I run it from Android Studio it runs thrice, but after exiting and when i open the app from the phone it just invokes once.

Comment: @RaguSwaminathan any idea how to overcome this issue?